# Python - How to take arbitrary string in path to a file via regex

Tags: python, regex, file, path

I have a path that I have assigned to a string:

```
string = 'pathos/llb_cube/uni/ToolSub.pm'
```

However the 'llb' prefix can be different string for each computer and I need to assign it to an arbitrary value that will read whatever the user's computer has set for this specific directory such as:

```
string = 'pathos/*_cube/uni/ToolSub.pm'
```

I cannot figure out what function or regex to use for this however.

Comment: "read whatever the user's computer has set for this specific directory" -- what does this mean? Have you solved this part yourself?

Comment: Have a look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) which supports globs of this type. Better suited than a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dot `.` to mean 'any character':

```
string = r'pathos/.*_cube/uni/ToolSub\.pm'
```

- I escaped the dot at the end of the string.
- The `*` asterisk denotes 0 or more repetitions.
- I used a raw string literal: `r'...'` so that I can write backslashes without having to escape them.

*If you need a certain number of characters use `.{x}`.* Now you can use regex to match your paths

```
for path in path_list:
    match = re.match(string, path)
    if match:
        print(match.group(0))
```

Comment: So the program is returning the string as simply just pathos/.*_cube/uni/ToolSub\.pm rather than recognizing '.*' to be a regex. :( Therefore when I try to check if the file path exists it is not recognizing because it is reading '.*_cube'